# How to fetch category tree of wiki?

Tags: php, web-crawler, wikipedia

I want to fetch all wiki category ids, category names ans parent category ids. But, I dont want to do full wiki installation on my own server. Is there an API or all the category data avaiale to any xml / bz file on wiki server? So I can use it?

I want to fetch all following categories in [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3aCategoryTree&target=Wikipedia_categories&mode=0&hideprefix=20&showcount=1&namespaces=)

Comment: NB: Wikipedia's categories are **not** a tree. There are many categories which are unrooted (not a member of any parent categories), or which form loops (parent category is also a child category).

Comment: see this page too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782410/finding-subcategories-of-a-wikipedia-category-using-category-and-categorylinks-t

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432254/wikipedia-category-hierarchy-from-dumps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have basically two options:

1. Use [the API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) (specifically [the `categorymembers` module](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aCategorymembers)) to recursively walk the tree (actually, it's not a tree, it's a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)). This means making a lot of requests, so doing this would be quite slow.
2. Download [SQL dumps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download) that contain category information. Most of the information you need is in the `categorylinks` table, but you will also need the `page` table to map page ids to their names.

Comment: I have imported the dump files of category and category links avaiable in above links provided by you. Now I can see 2 large tables in my DB category and categorylinks, with encrypted data. Now how can I fetch the category names and their relationship hirarchy by PHP? Any idea??? Please suggest.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything encrypted in those tables. But to get names, you will also need the `page` table, like I said. For information about the structure of the tables, have a look at [mediawiki.org](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_layout), starting with [the `categorylinks` table](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Categorylinks_table).

Comment: it is not encrypted, it is varchar binary, use  SELECT CONVERT(cat_title USING utf8) FROM category;