# Finding subcategories of a wikipedia category using category and categorylinks table

Tags: mediawiki

I downloaded the category and categorylinks table sql.gz files from mediawiki and generated the required tables:

category and categorylinks

Manual for the tables:
[CategoryLinks](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aCategorylinks_table)
[Category](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aCategory_table)

Consider the following category page of: [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aNoSQL)
The parent category of this page is Database and Database management. How could I get this information from the two tables?
The manual for category table says the following but I am unable to get that information:
"

> Note: The pages and sub-categories are stored in the categorylinks
>   table."

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432254/wikipedia-category-hierarchy-from-dumps

Answer (score 9):

Categories alone have no hierachy. It’s the category pages that make the subcategorization work. So you will also have to get the `page_id` from the `page` table to be able to resolve this relation.

It essentially works like this:

1. Category’s `cat_title` is a page title.
2. Find that `page_title` in the page table, get the `page_id`
3. Use the `page_id` to get the category link in `cl_from`
4. Get the parent category title from `cl_to`
5. Repeat from 2

Comment: You can convert category titles into page ids using the wikipedia API as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60669185/2919826.