# Wikipedia dump is not loadable with Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, docker, wiki

I already followed these two answers to restore wiki sql into postgres.

1. [how-to-build-wikipedia-category-hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27279649/how-to-build-wikipedia-category-hierarchy)
2. [import-sql-dump-into-postgresql-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842393/import-sql-dump-into-postgresql-database)

But I got this error messages:

```
psql:enwiki-latest-category.sql:125: invalid command \'s_soccer_players',1,0,0),
(247303133,'Young_Harris_Mountain_Lions_men' 
psql:enwiki-latest-category.sql:137: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`" LINE 1: INSERT INTO `category` VALUES (2,'Unprintworthy_redirects',1...
```

- environment:using [postgresql docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/)
- psql (PostgreSQL) 10.3 (Debian 10.3-1.pgdg90+1)
- [Wiki dump](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-category.sql.gz)

I used to thought that the error occurs because Chinese encoding, but it turns out that English doesn't work out as well. I'm a postgre noobie, any comment would be appreciated.

Comment: `category` :: it appears the .sql dump uses the silly mysql **backticks** to quote table and column names.

Comment: See here - https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Things_to_find_out_about_when_moving_from_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL - "MySQL uses ` (accent mark or backtick) to quote system identifiers, which is decidedly non-standard." So you would have to remove backticks (or replace them with double quotes) from the file before loading it into database.

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks a log, i'll give it a shot.

Comment: @JosMac You too, thanks a lot

Comment: I changed to mysql and it really works, thanks a lot ~

Comment: JosMac  wildplasser  Is there any tools which can convert wiki dump.sql into postgres's sql format ?
I found it every hard to integrate django with mysql in docker-compose ...